# QSortFilterProxyModel sorts only visually but returns wrong index

Tags: qt, sorting, listview, model, qml

I have a list model derived from `QAbstractListModel` with some data. Then a `QSortFilterProxyModel` model for sorting the first one.

```
proxyModel_.setSourceModel(qobject_cast<QAbstractListModel *>(&myListModel_));
proxyModel_.setDynamicSortFilter(true);
proxyModel_.setSortRole(myModel_.sortingRole());

view_->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &proxyModel_);
```

In qml:

```
ListView {
   model: myModel
   delegate: Rectangle {
      property int delegateIndex: index // I use this property for selecting the correct row from the list
       ...
   }
}
```

Then somewhere in the code I sort the model with

```
proxyModel_.sort(0, Qt::DescendingOrder);
```

The problem is that visually the listView is sorted properly, but when I click on some delegate, it returns the index from before the sorting. What could be a problem here? Thanks for help.

Comment: [This?](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapFromSource)

Comment: Yes, that's it, just found about that. Problem is I don't know how to use it exactly, as my index is an integer and this method takes QModelIndex. I'm having problems converting between themselves although it seems as something which should be quite an easy task.

Comment: What if you use currentItem instead of currentIndex to keep track of the selected item?

Comment: @S.Monteleone It seems that the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: @T.Poe provide a [mcve]